# alexbrainman/odbc golang package for odbc connection panicking

Tags: linux, github, go, odbc

I am trying to use alexbrainman/odbc package to connect to teradata, but it is panicking with the following error. I am running this on Linux  4.6.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

```
-bash-4.2$ go run bhn_equipment.go
panic: SQLSetEnvUIntPtrAttr: {㠳6} ㈵″㠳4

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/alexbrainman/odbc.init.1()
/home/xxx/github.com/src/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/driver.go:72 +0x7f
github.com/alexbrainman/odbc.init()
/home/xxx/github.com/src/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/utf16.go:56 +0x6c
main.init()
/home/xxx/github.com/src/bhn/bhn_equipment.go:25 +0x4e
exit status 2
```

here is my code
package main

```
import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"
_ "github.com/alexbrainman/odbc"
)

func main() {

db, err := sql.Open("odbc", "DSN=BHN-UAT")
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not connect to db:", err)
}

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("got an error:", err)
}

fmt.Println("Connection successful:", db)
}
```

Comment: DSN is okay as we are able to connect using perl

Comment: Did you follow the [Getting Started on Linux](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/wiki/GettingStartedOnLinux) wiki? Did you successfully install [the linux SQL drivers](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/wiki/LinuxSQLDrivers) and [unixODBC](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/wiki/InstallingUnixODBC)?

Comment: Yes I am following the wiki and already checked that unixodbc is there                                       `-bash-4.2$ rpm -qa | grep -i unixodbc
unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64
unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Did you also install the teradata driver?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/teradata-odbc-go-linux.rst

Answer (score 0):

you should use package https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/tree/for_issue_88
You can connect db, but not use utf16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).